# how to get jquery value from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to get perPage value in below jQuery code from input field whose value is a number as i have to create pagination for table who can control number of rows per page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',perPage:4});
});
```

Input field

```
<select input type="number" id="numberinput" />
<Option value="10">10</option>
<Option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** event handler to the dropdown and update `perPage` option.

```js
$('#numberinput').change(function() {
  $('#myTable').pageMe({
    pagerSelector: '#myPager',
    perPage: this.value
  });
});
```

```html
<select input type="number" id="numberinput">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes it is working but it keeps on adding number 1 to my paginator  please check the plunker for more clarification http://embed.plnkr.co/brRrQW3msRV5Nv4HHwDi/preview

Comment: @chetan , You need to empty the pagination list using `pager.html('')` ,http://plnkr.co/edit/XUnpyIYNYzHEZedUMQMB?p=preview

Comment: @chetan : check line `316`in updated plunker. In your code you are just appending the new new list item, u r not removing the existing list items

Comment: pranav thanks for your prompt reply but still it has a bug. shall i remove default value on line number 292. when i click on page number 2 it shows 7 records again.